# Prevent app has closed screen when killing a process

Tags: c#, .net, process, kill

I am killing a process using the following C# code

```
    using System.Diagnostics;

    private static void Kill()
    {
        var processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

        var p =
            processlist.FirstOrDefault(
                o => o.ProcessName == "MyApp");

        if (p != null)
            p.Kill();

        foreach (var process in processlist)
        {
            process.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

How can I prevent the dialog to either Debug or Close the program?

See

[image]

I would like the program to be closed immediately.

Comment: Doesn't the `p.Kill()` does that?

Comment: Since the other application is an unmanaged code app, I am not getting real debug information after I have clicked on the Debug button.

Comment: Why do you kill that process? You know, there is IPC to gently inform your own software to shut down. Killing on regular basis is only ok as a last resort or a quick bugfix, but not something you should think of as a *final solution*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not recommended but try this:

```
Process.Start("taskkill", "/F /IM [taskname].exe");
```